# NodeJS Postgres helper - release connection

Tags: node.js, database, postgresql, release, pool

I made postgres helper that I use to connect to database and execute queries. Code:

```js
var pg = require('pg');
var dbConn = require('../config.json').dbConn;
var pool = new pg.Pool(dbConn);

var status = {
    "OK": 0,
    "ERROR": 1
};
var message = {
    "success": "success",
    "error": "error",
    "databaseError": "Database error"
};

var helper = {
    query: function (query, params, success, error) {
        pool.connect(function (err, client, done) {
            if (err) {
                error({
                    status: status.ERROR,
                    message: message.databaseError,
                    data: err
                });
                return;
            }
            client.query(query, params, function (err, result) {
                //call `done()` to release the client back to the pool
                done();

                if (err) {
                    error({
                        status: status.ERROR,
                        message: message.databaseError,
                        data: err
                    });
                    return;
                }
                success({
                    status: status.OK,
                    message: message.success,
                    result: result
                });
            });
        });
    }
};

module.exports = helper;
```

It doesn't have logic to release connection after query executed. So after a while, I get database error : "Too many clients..."
Can someone tell me how to do it? Once I tried something (to call close() or release() function) but then it broke connection and I couldn't make new requests until I restart app.

Comment: To avoid issues with connectivity altogether, check out [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise) ;)

Comment: Hi, did you found any solution on this?

Answer (score 0):

The way you are doing this, you are not taking advantage of pooling and instead making a pool every time you use your helper. If you are using transactions, you should probably look at the pool.query convenience method that will take care of most of what you want:

```
const { Pool } = require('pg')

const pool = new Pool()

pool.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = $1', [1], (err, res) => {
  if (err) {
    throw err
  }

  console.log('user:', res.rows[0])
})
```

https://node-postgres.com/features/pooling#single-query